# How can I save progress in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello is there a way where I can save progress in HTML?

I'm making a clicker game and it's pretty annoying to play it and after an hour ur phone randomly closes

so im thinking to add a save and load button can anyone help?

Comment: You can use `localStorage` but if you want the savegame to survice changing browsers or devices you need a server and an account.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can save the progress of the game to local storage. If you're having trouble doing this, perhaps post your code so someone here is able to give you pointers

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.